# How to replace .innerHTML(String) with jquery html(String)?

Tags: jquery

I currently create a new table row with:

```
const billingNewRow = billingTable.insertRow(firstLineNum + billingNewRowNum - 2);
const boldIt = billingNewRowNum > 2 ? true : false
const newHTML = po.billingNewRowHTML(billingNewRowText, billingNewRowNum, boldIt, homeBillingLinked());
p(newHTML); // <b>Street3</b>&nbsp;<input type=text id=billing-street-3 disabled>
billingNewRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = newHTML;    //  <-- this works
```

if I try to use jquery and change that to

```
billingNewRow.insertCell(0).html(newHTML);
```

I get

```
billingNewRow.insertCell(...).html is not a function
```

Do I have to re-find the element in order to set the HTML ?
Is there another way ?

Comment: You can either convert the result of `billingNewRow.insertCell(0)` to a jQuery object using `$(billingNewRow.insertCell(0)).html(newHTML)`, because you have too many CPU cycles on your hands, or just keep using `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`billingNewRow.insertCell(0)` returns a DOM element, not a jQuery object. You need to use `$()` to convert it.

```
$(billingNewRow.insertCell(0)).html(newHTML)
```

But mixing DOM methods and jQuery like this is pretty strange. Why do you need to use `.html()` when you can just assign to `.innerHTML`?